# My extension of jQuery's next is acting unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am extending jQuery with a method to find the given selector using the given function as a way to traverse through this's siblings.

The reason I'm doing this is because jQuery's next() doesn't keep traversing the object's siblings, which is what I need.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    findSibling: function (selector, fn) {
      var $this = $(this),
          $sibling = fn($this);
      if ($sibling.length === 0){
        console.log("No " + selector + " found.");
      } else if($sibling.is(selector)) {
        console.log(selector + " has been found!");
        return $sibling;
      } else {
        $sibling.findSibling(selector, fn);
      }
    }
  });
}(jQuery));

$next = $this.findSibling('.line', function (object) {
  return object.next();
});
```

Even when the function finds what I'm looking for, $next remains undefined.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You know about [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) right?

Comment: @elclanrs: I think OP's doing something like `.nextAll('selector').first()`. I'm not sure what the callback is for.

Comment: FYI, `$this = $(this)` is unnecessary. Just use `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       $sibling.findSibling(selector, fn);
```

should be

```
       return $sibling.findSibling(selector, fn);
```

Comment: I wonder how many questions on SO would have been saved if JS were defined to do this automatically....